# escaped title attribute becomes unescaped in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am displaying photo with user generated title in popup using fancybox. while trying to get the escaped title displayed in the popup, I noticed the following behavior:

```
console.log( $("<a title=\"&lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;\">").attr('title') );
```

output: `<script>alert('test')</script>`

```
console.log( $("<p>&lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;</p>").html() );
```

output: `&lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;`

```
console.log( $("<p>&lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;</p>").text() );
```

output: `<script>alert('test')</script>`

my problem is that the title in the popup window is by calling `obj.attr('title')` which returns the unescaped title instead of the escaped one.

How do I get the escaped title in `obj.attr('title')` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you add an extra entity level to your title, like this:

```
$("<a title=\"&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;alert('test')&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt;\">").attr('title');
```

It depends on your server side environment, how you do this, a PHP example:

```
$title = str_replace("&","&amp;",$title);
```

Comment: my template system provides method to escapes tags by converting the characters "<", ">", "&" and """ to "&lt;", "&gt;", "&amp;", and "&quot;". the title="" content is filtered through the escape method when generating html page and I thought that would be safe enough. Now I need to do another escape of the & to &amp; I almost missed this one and it would be a XSS security hold if I did let it slip.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the getting, the setting is already wrong(the entities will be replaced by the browser).
Use `$().attr()` to set the title:

```
$("<a/>").attr('title',"&lt;script&gt;alert('test')&lt;/script&gt;")
```

..or replace all occurences of `&` with `&amp;`